# What's the meaning of "age-in-cohort" in the following quotation?

Tags: meaning

I don't understand what "age-in-cohort" means in the following partial sentence:

> "gender differences, age-in-cohort differences and differences in the experiences"

Can someone explain?

Comment: Hi, mina. I edited your question slightly to make it a bit clearer, but you might help readers understand the context of the phrase "age-in-cohort" better if you included more of the original quotation in your question.

Comment: If this were 'age-within-cohort differences', I'd certainly think in terms of the width of intervals (and, here, associated age differences). There is a large difference in maturity within a cohort of children aged say 4yrs one day to 5yrs no days, but all can end up in the same year group at school.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be in the context of a report on a statistical study of some topic.

A "cohort" is a group of the people (or things) being studied that have some common statistical characteristic. If that characteristic did *not* include their age, the results of the study might suggest that their age *should have* been included, and the data might be re-analysed taking age into account.

See https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cohort #2.1.